# Showing spash screen while loading .net framework

Tags: .net

I want to show a splash screen to user when user runs an application. It is possible to show a splash screen when loading windows form but, is there any i can show a splash screen when my application is being launched i mean when .net framework is loading in the memory.

Comment: Why is it even necessary. Your choice of .Net says you are definitely not targeting archaic computers, and loading a simple form for a splash screen is not too much work.

Comment: splash screens suck anyways.  Be nice to your users.  Don't show them a splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show something while main .NET application is not even started, you need an external launcher (written in WinAPI, maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

Anything you write using the .NET framework needs the framework loaded, so not that I'm aware of, no.  I suppose you could create some sort of application that launches your .NET application.  That first app wouldn't be able to use the .NET framework, though, and it seems a bit convoluted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you would have to either use a process to launch you application or implement your own runtime host. There's [an excellent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619883) on how to do the latter, but I doubt that it will be worth the trouble just to show a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, and experiencing delays, you can try this:

> http://tozon.info/blog/post/2008/08/11/Splash-Screen-in-WPF.aspx

It's a splash screen that is loaded/displayed as soon as possible, before the WPF components are loaded and initialised.